# File sync from network folder to azure blob without using the Command line (as in azcopy)

Tags: azure, azure-devops, azure-active-directory, azure-web-app-service, azure-pipelines

I want to sync my file from network folder to Azure blob but without using azcopy. Basically I dont want command line to be a part of the process but it should perform simple direct sync from file to azure blob. (if one file updates or deletes , the other storage should also update automatically). Is it possible to do that?

Comment: I don't understand. You want to copy files... without using any tooling that lets you copy files? Please explain *why* Azcopy isn't an appropriate tool for the job.

Comment: Since multiple people are supposed to do changes on the shared folder, its nor scalable to teach everyone to run the command after every delete, hence an auto sync is needed.

Comment: I feel like you're leaving out a critical piece of information here... **what** is being done on this shared folder? Why aren't you using version control?

Comment: Hi @shark, did the suggested solution work for you? Do let me know if it solved your problem else share more details so I can troubleshoot or else do accept it for helping other community members.

Answer (score 0):

•   You can use the ***‘Azure Storage Explorer’*** software in this case. But before using the Azure storage explorer, I would recommend you to please **ensure that the RBAC assignments are correctly assigned to the Azure AD members or people who will be accessing the Azure Storage Explorer software for this purpose**.

Kindly find the below snapshots for your reference on the demonstrated possibility of blob files syncing through the Azure Storage explorer software: -

***Storage explorer – 1***: -

[image: storage explorer - 1]

***Azure Blob storage***: -

[image: Blob storage - 1]

***Storage explorer – 2***: -

[image: Storage explorer - 2]
[image: Storage explorer - 3]

***Azure Blob storage***: -

[image: Blob storage - 2]

***Deleted file in Azure storage explorer and the same in Blob storage***: -

[image: Blob storage - 4]
[image: storage explorer - 5]

Thus, as you can see from the images above, **`the blob file synced from the Azure storage explorer is correctly synchronised from the local system to the Azure blob storage just by uploading the blob files from the local system through the Azure storage explorer to the blob container in Azure`**. Also, **when you delete the selected file from Azure blob storage, it is synced automatically in the Azure storage explorer application and shown accordingly**.

For more details on configuring the Azure storage account in the storage explorer, kindly refer the below documentation link: -

***https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/vs-azure-tools-storage-manage-with-storage-explorer?tabs=windows***